# Is there way to restrict openebs replicas to specific nodes in a k8s cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, storage, openebs

I have 20 nodes in my K8s cluster. I want storage to be saved only on 5 nodes where disks are attached. What are the configuration steps for me to restrict that storage pods are restricted to only these 5 nodes? …

Comment: A useful link on this is https://stackoverflow.com/a/50001861/9705485 and the links from it

Comment: What kind of a storage you want to mount to those pods, and where is it located?

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule the pods using Node Selector logic.More explanation has given in https://docs.openebs.io/docs/next/scheduler.html