# Expose volumes in Helm just like in docker

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, k3s

I'm creating an application that is using helm(v3.3.0) + k3s. A program in a container uses different configuration files. As of now there are just few config files (that I added manually before building the image) but I'd like to add the possibility to add them dynamically when the container is running and not to lose them once the container/pod is dead. In docker I'd do that by exposing a folder like this:

`docker run [image] -v /host/path:/container/path`

Is there an equivalent for helm?
If not how would you suggest to solve this issue without stopping using helm/k3s?

Comment: You just want to map a host directory to a container directory in kubernetes just like you did in docker and then use that configuration in a helm chart?

Comment: @rock'nrolla Exatly. In this way I won't lose new config files when the pod terminates and I'd like to use the same directory for future releases.

Comment: Can't you achieve the same by using a persistent volume claim?

Comment: You'd basically need to use `hostPath` as volume in kubernetes. You would preserve data when the pod terminates and also be able to add files dynamically. This should help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50001403/hostpath-as-volume-in-kubernetes

Comment: Some documentation around `Persistent Volume`, particularly of type `hostPath`: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/

Comment: @dishantmakwana Honestly, I'm new to k3s and helm so I don't really know, but I think what you suggested might help.

Comment: @rock'nrolla I think I misunderstood how to use helm and kubernetes from the very beginning. Can I use kubernetes yamls with helm? I thought helm would generate everything by specifying helm yamls. Thanks for the links

Comment: Helm YAML files _are_ Kubernetes YAML files, just with additional `{{ templating }}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Kubernetes (Helm is just a tool for it) you need to do two things to mount host path inside container:

```yaml
spec:
  volumes:
  # 1. Declare a 'hostPath' volume under pod's 'volumes' key:
  - name: name-me
    hostPath:
      path: /path/on/host
  containers:
  - name: foo
    image: bar
    # 2. Mount the declared volume inside container using volume name
    volumeMounts:
    - name: name-me
      mountPath: /path/in/container
```

Lots of other volumes types and examples in Kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I saw many guides on how to do this with kubernetes but I don't understand how this would translate in Helm. Right now I've values, configmap, persistentvolume and persistentvolumeclaim yamls (for the whole application) and a deployment yaml for the container in question. Where is the right place to set the hostPath?

Comment: @Jing This is a bit complicated at first: a Deployment creates Replica Sets, which create Pods, where the containers are. So the answer is you need to place it in `deployment.yaml` under `spec.template.spec` (that is pod template spec).

Comment: @Jing and if you want to use Persistent Volume Claim instead (this is like a named volume in Docker, i.e. you don't specify where on host it is, just it's name) you need to use a different volume type in `volumes`: `persistentVolumeClaim`. Under `persistentVolumeClaim` instead of `path` you use `claimName` and provide claim name from `persistentvolumeclaim.yaml`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. I think I misunderstood how to use properly helm and k3s.

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes has a dedicated construct for holding configuration files, [ConfigMaps](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/).  Helm in turn has support for [Accessing Files Inside Templates](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files/) which can help you copy them into ConfigMap objects.  A minimal setup here would look like:

```yaml
# templates/configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-config
data:
  config.ini: |
{{ .Files.Get "config.ini" | indent 4 }}
```

```yaml
# templates/deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment:
metadata: { ... }
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: config-data
          configMap:
            name: my-config  # matches ConfigMap metadata: { name: }
      containers:
        - volumeMounts:
            - name: config-data  # matches volume name: in this file
              mountPath: /container/path
```

You can use Helm's templating constructs in various ways here: to dynamically construct the contents of the ConfigMap, to set an environment variable saying which file to use, and so on.

Do not use `hostPath` volumes here.  Since Kubernetes is designed as a clustered environment, you do not have much control over which node a given pod will run on; you would have to copy these config files to *every* node in the cluster and try to update them all when a file changed.  That's a huge maintenance problem, especially if you don't have direct filesystem access to the nodes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So if I understand correctly with this approach: the configmap yaml takes all the files specified in the .Files.Get line (which can be dynamic) and injects them in a volume that will be mounted in the container at the given path "/container/path". But if I were to make changes to the files inside the container then I wouldn't have those changes outside. Also, I'd lose all the changes once the pod terminates right?

Comment: Is the application changing these files (so they do need to be persistent data) or are they just configuration?  If you change the template and `helm upgrade` the installation it will change the ConfigMap in the cluster (you may need to do a little work to restart the pods), but if the _application_ is changing the content, then it needs to be in a volume of some sort (not `hostPath` though since that won't necessarily survive a pod restart or the cluster autoscaler terminating the node).

Comment: Yes, the application inside the container is updating/creating/deleting those config files. I'd like to keep the state of those files after the pod is over so that I can use them again when I start another pod.

Comment: I'd say the reason behind mentioning `hostPath` volume is because that was what was asked in the question by the OP (equivalent of mapping host to container directory in kubernetes). It's not a best practice, but from what I figured that was beyond the scope of this particular question.